# How can I convert a .msdvd file to ... well, *any* video file that isn't .msdvd (Haven

Tags: conversion, avi, proprietary

I've used Windows Media Center to create several .msdvd files. I just want to convert them to something else, preferably .avi but any common format will do. I don't want to burn it straight to DVD and then rip from a DVD disk, which seems to be the suggestion elsewhere on the internet.

So is there a way I can:

- save straight to .avi from within Windows Media Center? ( I didn't see any option)
- use a freeware program to convert an .msdvd file to an .avi? (haven't yet found one)
- some other nifty trick? (can I 'save to dvd' without burning to a dvd, and then rip from the dvd file?)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find a tool for doing a direct conversion you can "burn" a dvd to an ISO image on your hard drive rather than a real disk. You can then read that as if it were a dvd using "iso reading" software such as any of the programs listed on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ISO_image_software)